# How poorly supported do claims need to be?

Tags: discussion, references, research

> Skeptics - Stack Exchange is for challenging *unreferenced* notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results.

What about claims that are well referenced? For example, you can often find a lot of medical references for any kind of popular diet, but skepticism would happen because it conflicts with a lot more medical references.

For example, the Atkins diet claims that fat does not make one fat or cause heart problems. While it has a basis for a lot of those claims, it flies in the face of other stronger medical research.

So how much research has to be done on a claim before it no longer qualifies as a Skeptics SE question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such limit, for example we accepted the following questions which are skeptical of basic, well supported science:

- [Is the Earth 6000 years old?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/is-the-earth-6000-years-old/)
- [Demonstrable and repeatable examples of evolution](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/demonstrable-and-repeatable-examples-of-evolution/)
- [Has man walked on the Moon?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/has-man-walked-on-the-moon)

The wording in the FAQ is a bit misleading. The claims do not need to be referenced, but they also do not need to be UNreferenced.

Comment: The moon walking does seems to be a biased claim, as the same people providing evidence for it are the ones getting funding for such projects :) But I see what you mean.